# how to download data from server before open the model screen?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

could you please tell me how to download data from server before open the model screen?I am able to download data from server using http request .But I have few question first is it the best way to download data from server before open model screen .secondly how to send data in model .In other words I need to send download data object in model screen to display the contend of web service .could you please help me how I will do that ?

here is my code

on button click I call web service

```
  $scope.openmodel=function(){
```

I need to send webservice data on model screen

```
<ion-modal-view>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
    <h1 class="title">departure</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content scroll="false">
    <ion-scroll direction="y" class="departurecontainer">


        <div class="row rowclass" ng-repeat="obj in data.data">
            <div class="col">
                {{obj.schDepart}}
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                {{obj.expDepart}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-balanced">
    <h1 class="title">Footer</h1>
</ion-footer-bar>
  </ion-modal-view>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be in your $scope.openmodel variable

```
$scope.openmodel = function(){
    $http.get("http://caht.firstrail.com/FGRailApps/jservices/rest/a/departure?crsCode=PAD")
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data; // you forgot to set the data to $scope.data
        alert(data);
        console.log(data);
        $scope.modalFirst.show();
    }).error(function (err) {
        alert(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: is the best way to to call webservice before open the model

Comment: you are on the right track with $http.get, wait while i try it on codepen

Comment: sir actually I apply your solution on code pen .it works I have Question it is best way to call service or is there any resolve type method

Comment: we use resolve function before moving to another view .can we use resolve function

Comment: `.success` does resolve the promise created by $http.get

Comment: I would advice you to create a service for all your http request. Controller should only have logic in them, all the Async data request should be made in services/factory. Its just good practice.

Comment: ^ it is true, controllers should really only 'glue' thing together

Comment: @KaranKumar couls you use code pen ...I am also trying to make factory or service

Comment: @KaranKumar mean how I use service